# PDF for length of Laplace-distributed vectors

Tags: laplace-distribution

I am interested in finding an analytic expression for the length of a 3-vector whose components are distributed according to a Laplace distribution with zero mean and the same scale parameter.

I have been unable to find anything useful so far in the literature, but it seems from my numeric tests that the answer should be close to $r^2 e^{-r/\lambda} dr$, where $r = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$ and the $x_i$ are Laplace variables with zero mean and exponential scale parameter $\lambda$. My heuristic result makes some sense to me from a transformation to spherical coordinates.

It would already help if I knew something more about the distribution of $r^2$ (for normally-distributed $x_i$, I know that I would get a $\chi^2$ distribution).

I would appreciate any hints or literature pointers you might have.

Thanks!

Comment: _Length_ of a vector is generally considered to be a nonnegative quantity and so why are you modeling it as a _Laplacian_ radio variable rather than an _exponential_ random variable?

Comment: Exponential distributions are perfectly fine, I would appreciate any input in that regard as well. It is just that my physical problem starts out with a Laplace distribution (these are real-space vectors pointing in all directions).

Comment: Are the components independent?

Comment: Yes. They are independent, but drawn from the same distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $X_1, X_2, X_3\sim\text{Laplace}(0,b)$, iid for a parameter $b$.

[Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) $|X_i|\sim\text{Exp}\big(\frac{1}{b}\big)$.

[Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) $X_i^2=|X_i|^2\sim\text{Weibull}\big(b^2,\frac{1}{2}\big)$.

So your question is answered by the sum of three iid Weibull variables with common scale $b^2$ and the specific shape $\frac{1}{2}$.

Unfortunately, [there does not seem to be anything on the sum of iid Weibulls in general](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_calculate_the_sum_of_two_Weibull_random_variables), and [convolving even only two Weibulls with shape $\frac{1}{2}$ exceeds WolframAlpha's standard computing time](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28-sqrt%28%28z-y%29%2Fb%29%29*exp%28-sqrt%28y%2Fb%29%29%2Fsqrt%28y*%28z-y%29%29+for+y+from+0+to+z).